# I can't delete fields in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, sql-delete

I need to delete to generate a form to select in checkboxes which users I want to delete from the database. To search the users and generate the form I use this code:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');
$busqueda =""; 
$busqueda=$_POST['busqueda'] ;
// funcion para convertir el contenido de un array en un string
function makestring($array)
  {
  $outval = '';
  if (is_array($array)) {
   foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
    if(is_array($value))
      {
      $outval = makestring($value);
      }
    else
      {
      $outval = $value;
      }
    }
}

  return $outval;
  }

if ($busqueda!=""){
    $busca = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE
        usuario LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
    echo "<form action='borrar.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    while ($array= mysqli_fetch_array($busca)){

        $user=makestring($array);
            echo"Usuario: <input type='checkbox' name='borrar_usuario[]' value='$user' />$user<br/>";
    }
    echo " <input type='submit' name='boton' value='eliminar' />";

   echo "</form>";
}
$all =$_POST['todos'] ;
if ($all=='borrar_todos'){

    $busca = mysqli_query($con, "select usuario from usuarios ");
    echo "<form action='borrar.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    while ($f =  mysqli_fetch_array($busca)){
        $user=makestring($f);
        echo "Usuario: <input type='checkbox' name='borrar_usuario[]' value='$user' />$user<br/>";
    }
    echo " <input type='submit' name='boton' value='eliminar' />";
    echo "</form>";
}

?>
```

I use this code to collect the data from the forms with this code:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

if(isset($_REQUEST["borrar_usuario"])) { 
    $del_user = $_POST["borrar_usuario"];
    $mensaje =  "¿Está seguro que quiere eliminar el usuario <b>$row[usuarioNombre]</b>?";
}
// mostramos el mensage
echo $mensaje;
    mysqli_query($con, "delete usuario, password, descripcion from usuarios 
        where usuario in like '$del_user'");
    echo "usuario borrado";
    header('refresh: 3; url= exito.php');
?>
```

But it doesn't delete anything in the database. Any help please?

Comment: You can't use `DELETE` to erase _fields_ in a database, `DELETE` will only delete entire _rows_.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE deletes the entire row from the database. You question feels like you need to Empty some specific fields. Try the following Code

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE usuarios SET usuario = null, password =null,
              descripcion=null where usuario like '$del_user'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to empty a field or fields, you need to use `update usuarios set usuario = '', password = '', descripcion = '' where usuario like '$del_user'"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this as the delete query

```
"delete from usuarios where usuario = '$del_user'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you delete one user at the time:

```
delete from usuarios where usuario = '$del_user'
```

or this if you delete more users and have `id`s in  comma(`,`) delimited list

```
delete from usuarios where usuario in ('$del_user')
```